# Proving a combination problem?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Given n and r are positive integers, how should I go about proving this statement? I tried using the combination forumula but I didnt really came close of solving it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Outline:** Use the following perhaps more familiar identities:
$$\frac{r}{n}\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}.\tag{1}$$ This can be proved combinatorially, or mechanically by expressing the binomial coefficients using factorials.

The *Pascal Identity* 
$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}\tag{2}$$ may also be useful. This also can be proved by a combinatorial argument, or by expressing the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials, and doing some algebraic manipulation.

We do not really have to use these identities. Expressing the binomial coefficients on the right-hand side in terms of factorials, and doing algebraic manipulation, will also work.